# AnimationDrawable not working in Fragments.

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

For a clear version please use this link sorry for my laziness but I'm searching for a solution from 4 hour and now I'm tired please help me stackoverflow gods

[image]

www.imgur.com/a/ML2snR1

Comment: Cann you Attach Screenshot of exception and screen instead of taking photo? image is not clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"constraintLayout" is null if you see. Don't use getActivity().findViewById(), rather use view.findViewById().

```
constraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. This worked after 4 hours of searching i was going crazy. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your constraintLayout is null
because u used to initialised it getActivity.findViewbyId() . replace get activity with view
so it will be

```
constraintLayout= (ConstraintLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
```